# Cannot control Windows Form objects from another method in the same file as the Windows Form

Tags: c#

I have recently started work on a large project in .net (C#) and I have encountered a bug in my code. I have eventually tracked it down, but I would like a bit of assistance in fixing it, if possible. I regularly have to call a method called UpdateUI, which would be great, except that any code in it does not affect the UI whatsoever! This method is public, and not static (though I have tried it static, and with an object reference, to the same effect) and is located in the same file as the Windows Form I am trying to update. I have cut out most of the code for simplicity, I have just shown you this to show my declarations etc. I would just like to ask what very simple hole I have blundered into that I really should not have!

Thanks so much for reading this,

Richard

```
public partial class ScanStatus : Form
{
    public ScanStatus()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label3.Enabled = true;                 

        // Some code. When "label3.Enabled = true" is placed here, it works perfectly.
    }

    public void UpdateUI()
    {
        label3.Enabled = true;

        // However, the above "label3.Enabled = true" does absolutely nothing, no exception, nothing.
    }                  
}
```

Comment: That looks fine to me.  I would reconsider your premises; you must be missing some other thing that is happening.

Comment: Is UpdateUI even being called? If you could post a short but *complete* example, it would really help...

Comment: I can confirm, using Breakpoints, that UpdateUI is being called, but thanks for the tip, and sorry for not mentioning this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code by adding one line to the method:

```
public void UpdateUI()
{
    label3.Enabled = true;
    this.Show();
}
```

If my guess is right, you'll now see *two* forms.  One with the enabled label.

Nope, you can't create a reference to an existing form with the new operator.  You have to store that reference when you create the form so you can reuse it later.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried this. I think I may now have worked it out, but need to run this by you experts. I did get no exceptions at all, just nothing working. When I added your new line, I did get an exception, and then the second window loaded, but badly, all the labels were covered with white boxes. The exception was System.InvalidOperationException: DragDrop registration did not succeed. ---> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it

Comment: Continued from above. I think I see my mistake now. This was (safely) called from a Background Worker, and this is my problem, isn't it; I need to call this from a Frontend thread? Is this correct, and is this the cause? As you can see, I am fairly new to multi threading, but I can say that nothing is being accessed at the same time, I have been careful. Just looking up exception to see what I can do myself. Thanks again for all of the help, all of you, 

Richard

Comment: Sounds like two bugs in your program.  Using the wrong form reference *and* trying to update the form from the wrong thread.  Fix your BGW code first.

Comment: Thanks, will fix that now. Just looked up the error, and after doing so disabled Drag-and-Drop which is not strictly required, and can be battled with later if I ever do need it. That stopped the error, but the labels still have white boxes around them. Will change that BGW code, and report back on how things are going.

Comment: All fixed! Thank you all so much for your help; without any one of you, I would not have got to this stage. You all added one crucial piece of the jigsaw, and now I get no exceptions, no white boxes, and UpdateUI does now update the UI! << On my original window, and no second window opens now! Thank you all once again for all of your wonderful help!

Richard

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that the code that calls UpdateUI is using the correct instance of the form (the same one as you're showing) so that you don't have two instances of it, one visible and one hidden.

Also, make sure that UpdateUI only is called from the UI thread (this is more a general thing since this would give an error rather than nothing happening).

If that doesn't help, post the code where you're calling UpdateUI (and where you're getting the object reference that you use to call it).

Comment: My current calling is:

                ScanStatus ScanStatus = new ScanStatus();
                ScanStatus.UpdateUI();

Is this right? Thanks!

Comment: @Richard: That does not look correct since you're creating a new instance of `ScanStatus`. You need to keep track of a reference to the original form.

Comment: Thanks! That was one more crucial thing that needed fixing, and was fixed by you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting cross thread exceptions? maybe you are updating UI from a non-UI thread. Consider using BeginInvoke()

Comment: Thanks very much. You were the one who reminded me of Frontend and Backend threads, so thanks very much!